# Pass callback into function to register on scala future onComplete method

Tags: scala, callback, future

I was to use the `onComplete` method on a scala future, as described [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#callbacks).

The basic idea looks like this:

```
def getPosts(url: String, callback: Try[HttpResponse[String]] => Unit) {
  val f: Future[[HttpResponse[String]]] = Future {
    val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http(url).get()
    if (response.code > 399) {
      throw new Exception(s"Error sending to ${url}")
    }

    response
  }

  f onComplete callback
}

val cb= {
  case Success(response : HttpResponse[String]) => succesfulWrites += 1
  case Failure(err) => totalFailedWrites += 1
}

getPosts("localhost:8000/widgets", cb)
```

However, I keep getting errors such as `missing parameter type for expanded function. The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known.` (regarding the line where I define `val onComplete`), or other similar errors saying I'm doing it wrong.

As I am new to Scala, I recognize I could just be misunderstanding the best way to do this. I'm having a hard time finding examples though for what seems to be a fairly common use case. Am I thinking about futures/callbacks in scala incorrectly? If not, is there a simple end-to-end example for this scenario (passing callbacks as an arg into a function that uses futures)?

Comment: @jwvh thanks, that's helpful in itself. I'll update the question so that answers can focus on the callback part itself.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Can you explain what you mean by "custom function"? Google returns articles about Spark UDFs rather than anything specifically scala related :/

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ok I think I understand, I will rewrite to make clearer, and let me know if that makes sense. I will rename the function I define from `onComplete` > `cb`, since it is a callback I want to pass into `getPosts`

Comment: @RyanQuey ah it is clear now, sorry for the confusion. - Anyways, I would like to point out that `onComplete` is usually discouraged, it would be better to use `foreach` or other combinators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected type of [pattern matching anonymous function](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions)

```
{
  case Success(response: HttpResponse[String]) => successfulWrites += 1
  case Failure(err)                            => totalFailedWrites += 1
}
```

must be explicitly specified, so instead of

```
val cb = {
  case Success(response: HttpResponse[String]) => successfulWrites += 1
  case Failure(err)                            => totalFailedWrites += 1
}
```

we have to write something like

```
val cb: Try[HttpResponse[String]] => Unit = {
  case Success(response: HttpResponse[String]) => successfulWrites += 1
  case Failure(err)                            => totalFailedWrites += 1
}
```

Here I am assuming the signature of `getPosts` is

```
def getPosts(url: String, callback: Try[HttpResponse[String]] => Unit)
```

More precisely only the **parameter** type (as opposed to also return type of the whole function type) needs to be explicitly provided, meaning the following would also work

```
val cb = (x: Try[HttpResponse[String]]) => x match {
  case Success(response: HttpResponse[String]) => successfulWrites += 1
  case Failure(err)                            => totalFailedWrites += 1
}
```

Comment: Follow up question: when defining the callback, I found that I could use 
`val onComplete : PartialFunction[Try[_], Unit] = {...` or the solution you suggested, but cannot use `PartialFunction` and pass in a specific type to `Try`, ie: 

`val onComplete : PartialFunction[Try[HttpResponse[String]], Unit] = {`. The latter returns error: `not a legal formal parameter. Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.`. Why doesn't this last way work? I'm just having trouble understanding these different scala syntaxes.

Comment: @RyanQuey I cannot replicate that, `PartialFunction[Try[HttpResponse[String]], Unit]` should work.

Comment: Ok strange, now it's working. I'm not sure what was happening before. So why can `PartialFunction` replace a pattern matching anonymous function without scala throwing errors about type mismatch?