# What is the difference between anonymous functions and partial functions?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, partialfunction

I was reading about scala anonymous functions [here](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) and saw that they can take the format:

```
{ case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn }
```

However, I thought that this was how partial functions were written. In fact, in [this blog post](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-use-partial-functions-in-scala-syntax-examples/), the author calls a partial function an anonymous function. At first he says that `collect` takes a partial function but then appears to call it an anonymous function ("collect can handle the fact that your anonymous function...").

Is it just that some anonymous functions are partial functions? If so, are all partial functions anonymous? Or are they only anonymous if in format like Alvin Alexander's example here:

```
val divide2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 42 / d
}
```

Comment: Ok so you are confusing many things. First what is a **function** in Scala. We can define it as a just a piece of computation, it is similar to a **method**, but the main difference _(there are many others)_ is that functions are values _(meaning they are instances of some class, so they are objects)_ whereas methods are not. -  A function literal is a special kind of syntax the language provides to create instance of the functions classes. - An anonymous function is just a function without a name so `map(x => x + 1)` is an anonymous function but `val f = (x: Int) => x + 1` is not.

Comment: Now a partial function is just a function that doesn't have a value associated for all the inputs. And the class `PartialFunction` class extends the `Function1` class, so all partial functions are functions. Finally, yeah the language provides especial syntax for creating partial functions _(which resembles pattern matching)_ however when the compiler expects a total function the same syntax can also be used and the compiler checks for completeness of the match.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez So related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63539155/6952495), I found I can pass in a callback to a future's `onComplete` method that either had a definition looking like `val cb : PartialFunction[Try[_], Unit] = {` or was an anonymous function (for example, see the anonymous functions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63539535/6952495).  Why could a partial function totally replace those anonymous functions without scala throwing any errors while checking types during compilation?

Comment: sorry I do not understand what is your confusion.

Comment: @RyanQuey there is an implicit conversion from partial function to regular function defined somewhere in the scala library. That's why you can pass `cb : PartialFunction[Try[_], Unit]` to `onComplete` and `getPosts`.  But it will throw an exception in case you try to run your regular function with parameter that can't be processed by partial function backed by this regular function.

Comment: @RyanQuey which won't happen with `cb` because it is partial function only by type definition, but in fact it is regular function because it can process all arguments.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko is not an implicit conversion is just basic subtyping. PartialFunction extends Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on pattern matching anonymous functions that you linked:

> If the expected type is SAM-convertible to `scala.Functionk[S1,…,Sk, R]`, the expression is taken to be equivalent to the anonymous
> function:
>
> ```
> (x1:S1,…,xk:Sk) => (x1,…,xk) match {   
>     case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn 
> }
> ```
>
> Here, each xi is a fresh name. As was shown here, this anonymous
> function is in turn equivalent to the following instance creation
> expression, where T is the weak least upper bound of the types of all
> bi.
>
> ```
> new scala.Functionk[S1,…,Sk, T] {   
>   def apply(x1:S1,…,xk:Sk): T = (x1,…,xk) match {
>     case p1 => b1 … 
>     case pn => bn   
>   } 
> }
> ```
>
> If the expected type is `scala.PartialFunction[S, R]`, the expression is taken to be equivalent
> to the following instance creation expression:
>
> ```
> new scala.PartialFunction[S, T] {   
>   def apply(x: S): T = x match {
>     case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn   
>   }   
>   def isDefinedAt(x: S): Boolean = {
>     case p1 => true … case pn => true
>     case _ => false   
>   } 
> }
> ```

Your first code snippet is a pattern matching anonymous function, but not necessarily a partial function. It would only be turned into a `PartialFunction` if it was given to a method with a `PartialFunction` parameter or assigned to a variable of type `PartialFunction`.

So you are right that just some (pattern matching) anonymous functions are partial functions (AFAIK, function literals defined with fat arrows, such as `x => x`, can only ever be used to create `FunctionN` instances and not `PartialFunction` instances).

However, not all partial functions are anonymous functions. A sugar-free way to define `PartialFunction`s is extending the `PartialFunction` trait (which extends `Function1`) and manually overriding the `isDefinedAt` and `apply` methods. For example, `divide2` could also be defined like this, with an anonymous class:

```
val divide2 = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x != 0
  override def apply(x: Int) = 42 / x
}
```

You probably won't see this very often, though, as it's a lot easier to just use pattern matching to define a PartialFunction.

---

In the blog post by Alvin Alexander you linked, the author refers to the pattern matching anonymous partial function literal as an anonymous function only because it happens to be both a partial function *and* an anonymous function. You could also define the function like so:

```
List(42, "cat").collect(new PartialFunction[Any, Int] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = x.isInstanceOf[Int]
  def apply(x: Any) = x match {
    case i: Int => i + 1
  }
})
```

It's no longer an anonymous function, although it's still an anonymous object that's the instance of an anonymous class. Or you could define a singleton object beforehand and then use that.

```
object Foo extends PartialFunction[Any, Int] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = x.isInstanceOf[Int]
  def apply(x: Any) = x match {
    case i: Int => i + 1
  }
}
List(42, "cat").collect(Foo)
```

No matter how you define it, though, it's a partial function.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous and partial are different concepts. We would not say the following function is anonymous

```
val divide2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case d: Int if d != 0 => 42 / d
}
```

because it is bound to the name `divide2`, however we could say `divide2` is defined in terms of the anonymous (function) value

```
{ case d: Int if d != 0 => 42 / d }
```

in the same sense `x` is defined in terms of anonymous value `42` in the following definition

```
val x: Int = 42
```

Orthogonal concept of *partial* refers to special subtype of function, as opposed to whether values of particular type are bound to a name or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of writing your pattern matching partial function.

```
val divide = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
    def apply(x: Int) = 42 / x
    def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x != 0
}
```

In essence, a partial function is a function that isn't defined for a set of inputs. It could be like in the example that it doesn't make sense to divide by 0, or you could want to restrict some specific values.

The nifty thing with partial functions is that it has synergies with orElse, andThen and collect. Depending on whether or not you're inputing a 0 in the divide function, your variable can be passed along to andThen if it wasn't a 0, can go through orElse if it was a 0. Finally, collect will only apply your partial function if it is defined on that input.

The way you create a partial function is usually through pattern matching with case as shown in your example.

Last thing, an anonymous function in Scala is like a lambda in Python. It's just a way of creating a function without "naming" it.

Eg

```
val f: Int => Int = (x: Int) => x * x
collect {
    case a: Int => 1-a
}
```

Comment: How come the scaladoc gives the following as an example of an anonymous function but there's a bound literal (f)?
    val f: Int => Int = (x: Int) => x * x

Comment: well technically speaking it is an anonymous function which then you assign to a variable thus binding it to a name.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks Luis Miguel :)